# How to completely remove Night Light 18.04 in Gnome 3.28.4

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I'm at my wit's end trying to get Night Light to work correctly.  Any tips on how to remove it completely in Gnome 3.28.4 running on Ubuntu 18.04.5?

Comment: So, you want to make Night Light work properly by removing it completely? Does it make any sense?

Comment: @blackappy What are the *exact* problems that you're facing while trying to get Night Light to work correctly? Also why are you trying to *remove* it (instead of, say, disabling it)? Please **[edit]** your question to clarify and also provide technical details of your  hardware and system.

Comment: mikewhatever, as I've stated in my question, I'm at my wit's end.  Therefore, I'm giving up and trying to remove it completely.

Comment: It's easiest to just disable it (safer too)   I use `redshift` myself and it conflicted with GNOME's night light, so I just disabled night light.   (it's part of GNOME, so if removed, there will always be the chance of it re-appearing with upgrades, or you having *release-upgrade* problems in the future so I'd recommend avoiding removal)

Answer (score 2):

Settings → Devices → Screen Display → Night Light → click and set the slider as required in the second window to turn it off (or set the conditions).

As guiverc says in his comment under the OP it is easier (and safer) just to disable it as upgrades increase the chance of it re-appearing and release-upgrades causing future problems with your system. So, in short, whilst it *might* be possible to remove it altogether it would be best just to disable it and maintain system integrity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question asks how to *remove* Night Light completely as apparently it doesn't work *correctly* in the OP's system. There's no indication that the OP asked for a basic tutorial on how to *enable* Night Light.